# how to make submitted variable to true, once the formgroup is submiteed and make it to false once the user changes some values in the form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have one FormGroup, once the user is submitted and form has some error, I make submitted variable to true and shows the error, after that, if the user make any changes in the form the submitted variable should be false and hide the errors.
Is there any way how I can do this? I am able to change the submitted variable to true, if the form has error and it is submitted, but if the user make any changes to the form after submittion, how I can set the submitted variable to false?

Comment: please provide the code,there are many ways to validate formgroup submission with or without a variable

Comment: You can subscribe to the `AbstractControl.valueChanges` or the `AbstractControl.statusChanges` observables and update your state as applicable to your needs. see https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your discription the error messages display after submit.
it's hard to maintaint the state of your form with your approche.
but you can use tricks like this :

```
  this.userForm.markAsPristine();
  this.userForm.markAsUntouched();
```

You can try another way :

Instead of display error after submit, you can benefit from reactive forms and display error instantaneous for each field of your form and the submit button can only be enabled if the from is valid.

N.B : if the error messge is from the backend side you can use à toast or snackbar.

Comment: Looks like it will work for me, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

inside your component's `ngOnInit()` function, subscribe to the `valueChanges` property of the `FormGroup`.

so that each time the `valueChanges` has a new emitted value you can reset the `submitted` boolean property to false.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.userForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.submitted = false;
   });
}
```

Comment: I know this, but how to call this valueChanges only once, after every submitiion and after the changes in the form?

Comment: you can `subscribe` to `valueChanges` after `submitted` being true and inside the fallback function of the `subscribe` you can `unsubscribe` from it. this is the only way but I think it **it will have a huge impact on the performance** to subscribe and unsubscribe that much

Answer (score -1):

*i think this can help you*

> **component.html**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-controls inputs" id="planName" formControlName="plan_name" />
            <span class="title" *ngIf="(newPlanForms.plan_name.touched || submitted) && newPlanForms.plan_name.errors?.required">
            Plan name is required
            </span>
```

> **component.ts**

```
submitted = false;

newPlanForm = this.fb.group({
plan_name:new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),});

onSubmit(value:any){
this.submitted = true;
....
.....}
```